# Swagger API wont allow me to post multiple IFormFIles

Tags: c#, api, post, swagger

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost("CreateEmail")]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        public async Task<ApiResponse<Guid>> PostEmailToProcess([FromForm]EmailToProcess email) 
        {
            try
            {
                var emailToAdd = new EmailToProcessDto(email);
                emailToAdd.Created = DateTime.Now;

                var emailId = await _emailRepository.PostEmailAsync(emailToAdd);
                
                foreach (var file in email)
                {
                    if (email.IFormFile != null)
                    {
                        await _contentUploadService.Upload(file, emailId.Data);
                    }
                }
etc
```

EmailToProcess Object:

```
{
    public class EmailToProcess
    {
        public string From { get; set; }

        public string To { get; set; }

        ...

        public List<IFormFile> IFormFile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, swagger is only letting me submit 1 FormFile. I am new to swagger and creating APIs so Im sure Im missing something small.

Comment: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/ "However, uploading an arbitrary number of files (an array of files) is not supported."

Comment: Multiple file upload is [supported](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/#multiple) in OpenAPI 3, but your library (Swashbuckle?) is generating an OpenAPI 2.0 API definition. Check if you have an option to produce OpenAPI 3 output, and update your annotations accordingly.

Comment: look at this [article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/testing-file-upload-with-swagger-in-asp-net-core-90269bc24fe8). it shows how do you upload mutliple files using swagger.